# How to store image name in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting an image from a table via query in SQL Server but I want to store its name in another table also in SQL Server. The following is the method that I have already done to get the image:

```
private void btnObtener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Server=***.**.***.***;database=--------; User Id = --------; Password = --------");    

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT NOMBRE_FOTO FROM TBL_FOTOS", connect);    

    SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);   

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("TBL_FOTOS");    
    byte[] MisDatos = new byte[0];    
    dp.Fill(ds, "TBL_FOTOS"); 

    DataRow myRow = ds.Tables["TBL_FOTOS"].Rows[0];  
    MisDatos = (byte[])myRow["FOTO"];  
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(MisDatos);    

    //Establecemos PictureBox
    pbVista.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

The following is the method to save the image name to the other table, it is important to note that I only want to store the name.

```
public string registrarImagen(string nombre, PictureBox pbVista)
{
    string msj = "Se registro la imagen";

    try
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_FOTOS_DISP (NOMBRE) VALUES (@Nombre)", connect);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Nombre"].Value = nombre;

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        pbVista.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        msj = "No se inserto la imagen: " + ex.ToString();
    }

    return msj;
}
```

The following is the view where I show the image that I get in a PictureBox and two buttons in one where I get the image with the method mentioned above and the other button to save the name in the new table:

[image]

The following is the save button action method and where I am presenting the error:

```
private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(img.registrarImagen(nombre, pbVista));
}
```

**ERROR:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I add exactly the error that appears to me

[image]

Comment: Check the scope of your `nombre` variable.  Most likely, it's not in the class scope, but rather in a private scope.  But it's clearly not visible where you're trying to use it.

Comment: If your question is about the error you are getting - please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code as we (similarly to compiler) can't figure out why "nombre" is no visible in that scope while "pbVista" is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also provide a TextBox or similar control, where the user would enter the name to store.

In your example Form image, I can see a PictureBox, but no control where the user could enter the name. Where should that name come from anyways, if not from the user?

Then, in your 'btnRegistrar_Click' method, you can reference the TextBox control to obtain the text, much like you already have done with the pbVista PictureBox

Comment: The name to be stored is the one obtained from the btnObtener_Click method in the "NOMBRE_FOTO" column of the query

Comment: Ok, but you never read it from the dataset there. If you want to keep it until after the user's postback you should at least store it somewhere. If not in TextBox, in a HiddenField for example. Welcome to the old and ugly Kingdom of WebForms, btw. :-)

Comment: How can I save the value of "NOMBRE_FOTO" somewhere and then use it and store it in the table TBL_FOTOS_DISP

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking it was WEBForms, but it's WINForms. Just store it on a class member variable.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can save the variable as a member of the class, I'm new to this from WINForms

Comment: @JohnDoe Just create a property on the "form class". You will find all relevant docs on the microsoft pages and also elsewhere on the net. Good Luck!